# Probability calculation of the chance that an occurrence does not happen

Tags: probability, statistics

Let me illustrate the situation: there are 93 "batches" and 25 "campagnes". A campagne is a series of batches that is done in the same period of time. So the average campagne length is 3.72, but let's say it is 4 batches per campagne. After each campagne, the process is resetted (cleaned etc., it is a chemical process).
Now I noticed that I have a bad occurrence in 14 batches, which ruins the "yield" of my batch. I also noticed that in those 14 batches, only 1 batch had a mildly bad yield on the first batch of a campagne while the others never happened on the first batch of a campagne (I suspect a cleaning issue, as the process isn't cleaned in between the batches in the same campagne).
My question is, what is the chance that 14 "bad" occurrences (bad yields) never happen on the first batch of a campagne, given the average campagne length is 4 batches?
I've never delved deep into the world of statistics and probability, but if anyone can help me out it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that a batch is bad seems to be $p={14\over93}$, so the probability of getting 25 campagnes with no bad batches in the first position, assuming that the probability is independent, would be $(1-p)^{25}=0.017$, so there is about 2% chance of this happening even if the bad batch appearing is not related to the position in the campagne (it is "independent of position" in probability talk).

Similarly the probability of having one bad batch in the first position is ${25\choose 1}p(1-p)^{24}=0.075$ so about 7.5%.

The expected value for the number of bad batches as the first value of the campagne is $3.7\pm1.8$, so normally we would expect between about 2 and 6  or so bad batches to occur as the first value. This is because it's a binomial distribution so the mean value is $25\times p\approx3.7$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{25p(1-p)}\approx1.8$.

Comment: Where did you get the numbers 3.7 and 1.8?

Comment: I've added the answer to the answer.